# Retrive array object from object in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var obj={"firstName":"John","lastName":"Smith","isAlive":true,"age":25,"address":{"streetAddress":"21 2nd Street","city":"New York","state":"NY","postalCode":"10021-3100"},"phoneNumbers":[{"type":"home","number":"212 555-1234"},{"type":"office","number":"646 555-4567"},{"type":"mobile","number":"123 456-7890"}],"children":[],"spouse":null};
```

I want to access the phoneNumbers field
So I use

```
phone=obj.phoneNumbers;
```

I get an array but without "phoneNumbers" field.I want to get someting like this:

```
{
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "type": "home",
      "number": "212 555-1234"
    },
    {
      "type": "office",
      "number": "646 555-4567"
    },
    {
      "type": "mobile",
      "number": "123 456-7890"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: and why should this be useful?

Comment: because my API ask for it

Comment: @Yakov You can check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a new object then

```
var phone = { "phoneNumbers": obj.phoneNumbers };
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add that part in:

```
var phone = {"phoneNumbers" : obj.phoneNumbers};
```

Although there should be a good reason for doing this (like, need to pass it to an API that expects exactly "x").  A single-property object is about as useful as the value of its single property.

Answer (score 1):

How about making a function and using it for other similar purposes:

```
function transform (prop, payload) {
  return { [prop]: payload };
}
```

And use it like:

```
phone = transform('phoneNumbers', obj.phoneNumbers);
```